# Resize AIR app window while dragging

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, desktop-application

So I've noticed Windows 7 has a disturbing tendency to prevent you from dragging the title bar of windows off the top of the screen. If you try - in this case, using an air app with a draggable area at the bottom of the window, allowing you to push the top of the window up past the screen - it just kicks the window back down far enough that the title bar is at the top of what it considers the 'visible area.'

One solution would be to resize the app window as it moves, so that the title bar is always where windows wants it. How would you resize the window while you're dragging it, though? Would you do it like this?

```
dragHitArea.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(e:MouseEvent):void{
    stage.nativeWindow.height += 50;
    stage.nativeWindow.startMove();
    stage.nativeWindow.height -= 50;
});
```

see what's going on there? When I click, I'm doing `startMove()`, which is hooking into the OS' function for dragging a window around. I'm also increasing and decreasing the height of the window by 50 pixels - which should give me no net increase, right?

Wrong - the first '`.height +=`' gets executed, but the '`.height -=`' after the `.startMove()` never runs.

Why?

Comment: **update** - If you're curious, I'm programming an air widget with fly-out menus which expand rightwards and upwards - and since those element can only be displayed within the boundaries of the application window itself (even though the window is set to be chromeless and transparent) I have to expand the application's borders to include the area that the menu 'pops up' into. In the extreme case, with the widget positioned bottom left, and the menus expanded completely across to the right side and top edge of the screen, the application area could very well cover the entire desktop.

Comment: The problem is, when it's expanded like this, if the user drags it up and to the right, it causes the 'title bar' area of the application window to move above the top edge of the desktop area, where it would normally be unreachable; and Windows automatically re-positions the window back below that edge once the `.startMove()` operation is completed.

So what I want to do is continually resize the height of the application for the benefit of the operating system so that the window's title bar will never be above that top boundary of the desktop area.

Comment: I wonder if anyone realizes that the correct answer is quite possibly "you can't," and if they submit it, they'll get this bounty thing?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking into the `NativeWindowBoundsEvent.MOVING` event?

```
stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.MOVING, windowMove);
private function windowMove(e:NativeWindowBoundsEvent) : void {
    trace(e.beforeBounds);
    trace(e.afterBounds);
    // resize window as needed based on these
}
```

references: Google, which led me to http://lowpitch.com/blog/nativewindow-using-air-windows-with-actionscript-part-3-of-3/ which led me to http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/NativeWindowBoundsEvent.html

`NativeWindowBoundsEvent.MOVING` is fired before the position actually changes, whereas `NativeWindowBoundsEvent.MOVE` is fired after the position has changed, if you were wondering. Thus you would need the MOVING event

(by the way, I was tempted to just say "you can't" without doing any research for the bounty... but felt that would be mean)

Comment: I'll give this a look when I get into the office tomorrow morning. I know, cutting it close. :)

Comment: Nope - add "e.curentTarget.height = 50;" in your event handler, and when this fires due to stage.nativeWindow.startMove(), the height never jumps to 50, regardless of what even you're listening for. I'm really thinking that this just can't be done - you can't resize the window while you're dragging it to reposition it, and you can't drag and drop the window in such a way that the title bar ends up above the desktop area.

Comment: I hope that you tried `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.curentTarget` heh. But anyways, if this doesn't work... well here is a possible workaround. Instead of using the built in thing, fake it. Attach the MOUSE_DOWN to what you would like to move the screen. Then, when MOUSE_DOWN is activated attach a MOUSE_MOVE and MOUSE_UP. In the MOUSE_MOVE you would manually move the window, resizing if necessary. In the MOUSE_UP you would remove the MOUSE_MOVE and MOUSE_UP. Note that MOUSE_MOVE should probably be attached to the stage.

Comment: yeah, that's still a possibility - the problem is, the OS's function for repositioning windows is so much smoother than AIR's, from what I saw... but I might have to end up doing it this way.

Comment: sorry I couldn't have been of much help. But at least you know that there's at least a possible way you could do it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a similar app, with fly-out windows, and after encountering some problems I've decided to get rid of the NativeWindows, and do everything in one chromeless window the size of the screen. 
I was resizing the window to the size of the screen every time the app was starting. I have designed a custom title bar with buttons and everything, and the main window of the widget was actually a Canvas, which I dragged around on the app's window. Same thing with the fly-out menus and windows: they were just components based on Canvas.
I had no problems dragging a component outside the visible area of the window, because it was the same as the screen.

But, like I said, it may be late to make such a drastic change.

Comment: Ah - I actually tried this, and it almost works, except for a particular use-case - a multi-monitor setup including uneven screens. Imagine a laptop screen and a projector, or a pair of screens one in horizontal and one in vertical alignment, or three screens in a triangle configuration - flash has a lot of trouble making a window that accurately spans the entire visible area, unless you've got a method?

Comment: It didn't cross my mind... I was happy with just one screen :)

Comment: Oh cornelui - trust me, do yourself a favour, and at least put together a dual-screen setup. You will *never* want to go back.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like it would be a funny effect and not all standard window behavior. Why do you feel the need to do anything? Why not let the user resize the window themselves if they need to?

Comment: I mean, it shouldn't matter why I want to do it, the question is *how* to do it... but because it probably does sound a little weird, I'll update the question to clarify.